# .NET Core - Using Visual Studio And Keeping It Cross Platform

Tags: .net-core

I've written a few things using .NET Core and like it a lot. So far, I have always used Visual Studio Code (which I think is very good and getting better all the time) and have enjoyed being able to pick up work on a Mac. I've been using Visual Studio less and less as I do more using .NET Core.

However, last night, I added a sln file using the dotnet core CLI, added a couple of projects to it and opened it up in Visual Studio 2017 and the experience was excellent. Having the tests at the side was very useful.

My question: If I start to use Visual Studio for my .NET Core projects (after starting them using the CLI), and tying them together using a sln file, does anyone know if there is likely to then be issues using VS Code for cross platform work, at a later date? I would like to take advantage of the IDE tools offered by Visual Studio but don't want to then make Visual Studio mandatory.

Comment: Normally, we won't answer specific tool questions here on this site, but I think yours focusses very clearly to the software development life cycle, and I hope you get an answer for this by someone who has experience in this.

Comment: @DocBrown, done that: TL;DR: no guarantees, but OP should be fine is they stick to cross-platform projects.

Comment: @DavidArno: well, don't get me wrong, but your answer (which I did not downvote) does not seem to describe any first hand experience with Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code for developing the same project. It looks more like an opinion about Microsoft's goals.

Comment: @DocBrown, interesting. I've recently been switching between VS2017, Code and Rider with a few solutions and have had no problems. But if my experience isn't typical, then my answer isn't of much use. So I've deleted it.

Comment: Are you aware that Visual Studio exists for the Mac?  Not VS Code, but the full VS

Comment: @DavidArno: well, if you have actually first-hand experience, your answer should reflect this, then it will probably received better by the community.

Answer (score 4):

We use dotnet core a lot, and mixing VS Code / Rider and VS was not a problem. Most problematical are projects in a solution which cannot be understand by Rider or VS Code. E.g. docker-compose projects (.dcproj) are created by VS to enable docker support. Building them on linux do not work and can lead to errors - there are ways around this (e.g. installing the stub from Rider oder just remove the cirtical projects from the build).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks like they're aware of this issue and have a solution: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6178